# python spyder 3.1.4 shortcut (macOS Sierra 10.12.4)

Tags: python, spyder

I've checked the shortcut for spyder in mac.

`F5`: run

`F9`: run selection or current line

However, those shortcuts are not working in my spyder!
Every time I have to select the lines I wanted to run or select all my code, and press `cmd+enter`, this is not efficient.

I tried to go to `keyboard shortcut` to change the setting but I couldn't change the default.

Where can I make it like `F5` run and `F9` run current line by putting my cursor on?

PS: it was working good in Windows10 when I hit `F5` or `F9`. I even don't need to highlight the line I wanted to run, I only need to put the cursor on the line and it works.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we don't forget to fix it in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold the fn key and then hit f5. To run: fn + f5

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Enter for running the code, or selecting all and then running the code